# Why does this regex wipe out all characters when a comma is entered in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, regex, html

I want to use the number type input field but strip out the dollar sign if it's entered (for browsers not Chrome).

But with the code below, if I enter 300, or 300.. etc it wipes out all of my entry.

What's going on?

```js
jQuery( 'input' ).keyup( function( ) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/\$/g, '*');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That because, when you set [`value`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-value), the [value sanitization algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#value-sanitization-algorithm) is invoked. For [number inputs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#number-state-%28type=number%29),

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the
>   element is not a valid floating-point number, then set it to the empty
>   string instead.

Since `300,` is not a valid number, the input is cleared.

Then, instead of replacing characters, a better approach would be preventing them from being written:

```js
jQuery('input').keydown(function(e) {
  if(e.key == '$' || e.which == 52 || e.keyCode == 52) e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number">
```

Comment: @JoshCrozier Oops, my solution only seemed to work because it produced a syntax error. Thanks.

Comment: Ah.. so it was only working because it wasn't being turned back into `type="number"`.. that makes sense... you still have my 1+..

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  I guess I realize now I didn't fully realize how the input type worked in terms of validation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The browser doesn't let you set the input value to a invalid string. The string `100,` is invalid for the input type number. [Please see the W3 documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html#input.number.attrs.value).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is behaving that way not because of your regular expression, but because the value of a "number" input is the empty string when it's not a valid number.

So, you type `1` ... `2` ... `3`, and everything is OK. But then if you hit `,`, the expression

```
this.value
```

is all of a sudden going to be the empty string. The `.replace()` call won't actually do anything, but you're assigning the result back to `this.value` so it gets rid of whatever was there.

Thus you could add a test to your code:

```
jQuery( 'input' ).keyup( function( ) {
  if (this.value.length)
    this.value = this.value.replace(/\$/g, '*');
});
```

However that's not really going to do you any good, because if a person *does* type a `$`, you'll get back the empty string and you can't fix it. You can't tell the difference from JavaScript between a "number" input that's *really* empty, and one that has text in it that the browser doesn't think is a nice number.

Comment: Personally I'm of the opinion that the HTML5 input types aren't really that useful on desktop "traditional" web UIs. On mobile devices however they're useful because they provide a way to guide the pop-up keyboard.